# Python-urllib3: ImportError from internal file

Tags: python, python-2.7, python-import, importerror, python-daemon

I have a python Daemon running.
This daemon communicates out using requests lib.
Everything is running ok for a while, but a few hours after it started running, suddenly it starts encountering ImportErrors like this one:

```
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/requests/__init__.py", line 55, in <module>
  import urllib3
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/__init__.py", line 10, in <module>
  from .connectionpool import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 31, in <module>
  from .connection import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 44, in <module>
  from .util.ssl_ import (
File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/urllib3/util/__init__.py", line 2, in <module>
  from .connection import is_connection_dropped
ImportError: No module named connection
```

It's always some internal module used by urllib3 (I also encountered errors when urllib3 tries to import socket, httplib and others, it's not a specific one), and importing that module in a console goes fine.

Restarting the daemon fixes the issue for a while, before it pops up again.

I am using __import__, and after reading a bit about Python's import system, I suspected it has something to do with this. This suspicion is lessened by the fact that I have another daemon on a different machine that uses it, and this issue never affects it.
**EDIT**: Both daemons use it to import a function, and pass it to a billiard subprocess, where the issue arises (not in the main daemon loop, but in the billiard subprocess using requests)

This locality caused me to reinstall the problematic machine. It didn't help.

I at a loss as to what causes this issue and how to solve it.

Any idea is welcomed.

Comment: How are you using `__import__`?

Comment: I am importing a function and passing it to a billiard subprocess. But as I mentioned, the same happens on another daemon without this issue. I realize now that this information is important, so I added it to the question.